# Customizing background in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self._window = tkinter.Tk()
self._window.option_add("*background", "green")
self._window.configure(background='green')
```

How can I instead of saying `self._window.configure(background='green')` say `background = <something else>`, maybe a `tkinter.Canvas` with drawings on it?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just create a `Canvas` which fills the entire `Tk()` parent?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a canvas that covers the whole window:

```
self.background = tkinter.Canvas(self._window)
self.background.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Once you do that, you can draw anything you want on the background. From this point forward, just make sure all other widgets are children of the canvas rather than the root window.